# Selecting the max value from 2 dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries d1 and d2 as shown below:

[image]

(I have a data frame where the columns contain dictionaries, Ive taken one value from it)

what I want to do is, compare these d1 and d2, get the common cities(d1 intersection d2) and see in d1 to find the city with the maximum value. If there is a tie between 2 or more cities in d1, then I plan on checking d2 values as tie breaker.

Even though I have this idea, I am not sure how to code it in an efficient manner since the data frame is about 100000 rows .I would like the code to take as minimum time as possible for execution. How would I achieve this?

In response to comment of @Joshua, I am putting the dictionary as text:

```py
d1:
{'Bangalore': 50.0, 'Vadakara': 6.25, 'Pathanapuram': 6.25, 'Kannur': 6.25, 'Adoor': 3.125, 'Kozhikode': 7.8125, 'Pathanamthitta': 4.6875, 'Thalassery': 1.5625, 'Coimbatore': 1.5625, 'Calicut': 6.25, 'Kanjanagadu': 3.125, 'Chennai': 1.5625, 'Perambra': 1.5625}

d2:
{'Bangalore': 45.0, 'Kozhikode': 28.333333333333332, 'Thrissur District': 21.666666666666668, 'Kannur': 3.3333333333333335, 'Wayanad': 1.6666666666666667}
```

Comment: what would the desired output look like for this example you posted?

Comment: In this case it will be Bangalore since it is clear majority in d1. But if there is a tie in d1, I want to check d2 and use that as tie breaker

Comment: desired output will be city name. thanks

Comment: What is the algorithm/calculation to determine the desired output? just the city with maximum value in d1 (include d2 only if tiebreaker) ? is that correct?

Comment: Also, can you post the arrays as text so that others can troubleshoot your code easily?

Comment: So first i want to take intersection of  d1 , d2 and keep only common cities. then, city with max value in d1 is output . if 2 or more cities tie , then d2 value as tiebreaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `max()` with custom `key=`:

```py
d1 = {
    "Bangalore": 50.0,
    "Vadakara": 6.25,
    "Pathanapuram": 6.25,
    "Kannur": 6.25,
    "Adoor": 3.125,
    "Kozhikode": 7.8125,
    "Pathanamthitta": 4.6875,
    "Thalassery": 1.5625,
    "Coimbatore": 1.5625,
    "Calicut": 6.25,
    "Kanjanagadu": 3.125,
    "Chennai": 1.5625,
    "Perambra": 1.5625,
}

d2 = {
    "Bangalore": 45.0,
    "Kozhikode": 28.333333333333332,
    "Thrissur District": 21.666666666666668,
    "Kannur": 3.3333333333333335,
    "Wayanad": 1.6666666666666667,
}

city = max(d1.keys() & d2.keys(), key=lambda k: (d1[k], d2[k]))
print(city)
```

Prints:

```
Bangalore
```

Comment: This works quite brilliantly and its fast. But, I did not completely understand what is happening. Could you explain the code please?

Comment: @Doof `d1.keys() & d2.keys()` does *intersection* of keys between two dictionaries. `max()` iterates over these common keys, using lambda to determine which key holds maximum value (using `d2` as *tie breaker*)

Comment: Yes,  Where or how is it using d2 as Tie breaker. This is the part i am trying to understand

Comment: @Doof the lambda function is creating tuples `(d1[k], d2[k])` and comparing them. If `d1[k]` is the same, then is using next element, `d2[k]`